# Postgres: Python: TypeError: SQL.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: postgresql

Hello I am getting error from my code, can someone help me please?

def query_builder(self, field_name, table_name, pkey, id):

```
    queryx=sql.SQL("select {field} from {table} where {pkey} = %s",(id)).format(
        field=sql.Identifier(field_name),
        table=sql.Identifier(table_name),
        pkey=sql.Identifier(pkey))
    
    self.cur.execute(queryx.as_string(self.conn))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using `psycopg2`.

If so the issues are, first:

```
"select {field} from {table} where {pkey} = %s",(id) ..."
```

Do not include the argument `(id)` in the string. Also this is not proper form for a single value in a tuple. Python requires it be `(id,)`, note the comma.

Second:

```
self.cur.execute(queryx.as_string(self.conn))
```

Should be:

```
self.cur.execute(queryx, (id,))
```

The `execute` is where you supply the argument. Also the composable `sql.SQL(...)` can be passed directly to `execute` without being run through `as_string`. See here [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for more examples.

**UPDATE**

To use "*" there are two ways:

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL("select * from {table} where {pkey} = %s).format(table.sql.Identifier(table_name), pkey=sql.Identifier(pkey))

--OR

cur.execute(sql.SQL("select {field} from {table} where {pkey} = %s).format(field=sql.SQL("*"), table=sql.Identifier(table_name), pkey=sql.Identifier(pkey))
```

**Warning**, the second does allow for SQL injection as `sql.SQL()` does not escape values.

As to multiple fields the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql) section of the docs has multiple examples. For instance:

> If part of your query is a variable sequence of arguments, such as a comma-separated list of field names, you can use the SQL.join() method to pass them to the query:

```
query = sql.SQL("select {fields} from {table}").format(
    fields=sql.SQL(',').join([
        sql.Identifier('field1'),
        sql.Identifier('field2'),
        sql.Identifier('field3'),
    ]),
    table=sql.Identifier('some_table'))
```

Comment: Adrian thank yo so much, it really works. I appreciate it. I have 2 short questions 
1)what if  I want to obtain all the fields? When I send "*" argument into the field_name parameter I receive an error.

2)If I want to obtain multiple fields like FullName, EmailAddress, how to structure the arguments?

Comment: Yes, I do use psycopg2, Than you so much.

Comment: I understand thank so much for your time, Adrian. It is very clear.

Comment: If it answers your question will you accept the question and/or upvote it?

Comment: Hi Adrian, of course I would. I was searching for where I can upvote for you, I am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: I got it now, I already clicked the triangle up, I hope you can see it.